# Creating a "dead area" on the Windows desktop

Tags: windows, desktop, delphi-xe, multiple-monitors

One of our applications duplicates an area in the top left corner of the monitor and displays it to the public. Any of our other applications are prevented from covering this area, you cannot drag any of them over this area (they hit a "wall"), otherwise they would be visible publicly.  However, if a user starts another application, say IE, it can display over the restricted area. Is there a registry setting or something that we can set that will prevent ALL applications from using this part of the desktop, eg. 300x200. I could set this value when our program starts and restore it when it closes, and have a separate application just to restore it just in case!  It is not a serious limitation if the whole of the side or top could not be used, ie. if we block out the whole first 300 pixels on the left this would be acceptable. We are running W7-10 depending on the customer, programming is done in Delphi XE (at the moment).

Comment: It would be beneficial if you made an [edit] to your question and used some paragraphs. As it is now, the wall of text is difficult to read. When you're typing your post, you can use Enter just as you would in any other text area. You should also probably replace the delphi-xe tag with a simple delphi tag, as there doesn't appear to be anything in your question specific to a particular Delphi version.

Comment: I am guessing something is displayed in this area or it would not be visible to the public. Therefore what you are asking for is illogical since what you are displaying would no longer be able to be displayed if what you ask for were possible.

Comment: Sorry for the obscurity of my question.  I will reword it a bit better and I have realised that my situation was actually a "catch 22" as pointed out by Dsm.  What I am really after is "stay on top".